# Removing rows of a QSortFilterProxyModel behaves badly

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have an application which contains a `QTableView` for which I would like to have the possibility to sort its contents but also to remove one or more rows. Below is an example code that implements this.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class NeXuSFilesModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    fields = ['col1','col2']

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(NeXuSFilesModel,self).__init__(parent)

        self._nexus_contents = [['aaa','111'],['bbb','222'],['ccc','333']]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):

        return 2

    def data(self,index,role):

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._nexus_contents[row][col])

        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def headerData(self, index, orientation, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return NeXuSFilesModel.fields[index]
            else:
                return index + 1
        return None

    def removeRow(self, row, parent):

        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(),row,row+1)
        del self._nexus_contents[row]
        self.endRemoveRows()

        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):

        return len(self._nexus_contents)
 

class NeXuSDataTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(NeXuSDataTableView,self).__init__(parent)

        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete:
            model = self.model()
            selected_indexes = self.selectionModel().selectedRows()
            source_indexes_rows = sorted([model.mapToSource(index).row() for index in selected_indexes],reverse=True)
            for row in source_indexes_rows:
                model.sourceModel().removeRow(row,QtCore.QModelIndex())

        super(NeXuSDataTableView, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        self._table = NeXuSDataTableView(self)
        model = NeXuSFilesModel(self)

        proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)

        self._table.setModel(proxy_model)
        self._table.setSortingEnabled(True)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self._table)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    _ = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

When I run that code, I fall into several problems for which I could not find the solution or could not understand the explanations given by the various sources I could find.

1. When the program starts, the data is showed initially in the wrong order. Indeed, it is displayed in descending order whereas I would like to display it in ascending order
2. When I remove one item, it removes actually two items !

Would you have any idea about what is wrong with my implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About both your questions:

1. proxy_model.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder) after self._table.sortSortingEnabled(True) results in an ascending order:

```
        self._table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        proxy_model.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self._table)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.show()
```

2. Using `self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(),row,row)` will remove only one row.